# Use jQuery to clone list item with alternate colors when link is clicked

Tags: jquery

what is the easiest way to alternate color of the cloned list item?

Every time link is clicked I would like list item to be cloned and added to the bottom of the list, but every other item on the list should have class 'highlight' added.

This is the link to [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Klikerko/BXzY5/) where I have everything done except alternating color part.

This is an example how produced html should look like:

```
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li class="highlight">some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li class="highlight">some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li class="highlight">some text</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use CSS to highlight your rows?

Comment: I agree, CSS would make sense unless you wanted more flexibility in the color for each odd/even row

Comment: I need more flexibility with highlighting li's. With accepted solution I can have only cloned li's highlited while with css only solution whole list must get alternate color li's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#">Add More</a>
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>    

$('a').click(function() {
    var link = $('ul li:first').clone();
    if($('ul li').length % 2 != 0) {
        link.addClass("highlight");
    }
    link.appendTo('ul');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'd maybe add handling in there in case there's another class already present in the `.attr` call. +1 regardless :)

Comment: Any particular reason you chose .attr() over .addClass()? just curious :)

Comment: ahh yeah - samccone answer`s `addClass` would be more appropriate for adding the class.

Comment: @melee - no reason, and I changed it - `addClass` is much better

Comment: @Marek Karbarz ok cool, I was wondering if there was a performance benefit or something.

Comment: This code performs best because it appends `highlight` class only to the cloned elements, not to the whole list. This way if there is more than one item in the list already those will not be highlighted when new list item is added. Thanks Marek.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#cloneli').click(function() {
    $('#test li:first').clone().appendTo('ul');
    $('#test li:odd').addClass('highlight')
})
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/V8CNA/).

Comment: wow this is really a smart way to do things, alas tho it is limited in the flexibility

Comment: Hi Hussein, your code looks good only thing is that it's duplicating whole list on every click. You just missed to add ":first". Other that that this looks like the best solution so far. Thanks!

Comment: @klikerko, If you check my initial post and jsfiddle, I had the  `:first` there, but later edited, removed it and kept it up to you to choose which `li` he you want to clone. Anyway, I put it back.

Comment: @klikerko, both my code and the accepted answer are similar in performance. Mine is actually faster in chrome and contains less code. Check http://jsperf.com/li-heightlight.

Comment: Thanks Hussein, I decided to chose Marek's code because it gave me little bit more flexibility. His code highlights only new li's so if I have 10 list items at a beginning and then I clone one only that new one will be highlighted. I know this was not requirement but I liked this idea. Both solutions are great and I like your code because it's more readable and shorter. Unfortunately I can chose only one as final solution. Thanks again for helping with this one and doing extra step to compare both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

http://jsfiddle.net/BXzY5/2/

Answer (score 1):

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WbxR/). Basically, get the last member, see whether it has highlight set, and toggle the highlight class.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var newNode = $('ul li:last').clone();
    newNode.toggleClass('highlight');
    newNode.appendTo('ul');
    return false;
});
```